# CSS - Adding padding to Anchor isn't moving image

Tags: html, css

I am stuck right now, trying to add space around my anchor tag. When I add padding, it just makes the width larger, and the background image stays in place.

What I'm trying to do is make it so when I add padding to the home anchor tag, the home image moves.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mwJUY/

html:

```
<ul id="navbar">
    <li><a id="homebutton" href=""><span>Home</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Services</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Resources</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">News</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Clients</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Association</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to position your background image using `background-position`.

Example:

```
#homebutton {
background-position: center top;
}
```

The first value is the x coordinate, the second is the y coordinate.
You can use px, em or percent.

***EDIT:***

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mwJUY/4/)

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example where I used: `background-position: center 5px;`

Answer (score 0):

try giving `margin: 20px` and try

here's the fiddle [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mwJUY/1/)

The main reason for this is that padding creates a gap between the control boundry and its content  while margin creates a distance from the parent container

when you apply padding the control size remains the same and so the background actually fits entirely. either add an image tag and source or use margin

Answer (score 0):

You can add the image inside the anchor.

```
<a href="blah">
    <img src="blah"/>
    <span>Home</span>
</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mwJUY/5/